# Recursive dataset method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have return one recursive function which call itself as follows, but I am unable to break it, this is my code

```
public DataSet GetTableInfo(string sItem, double dAmount)
{
   string str = string.Empty;
   double d = 0;

   Dataset ds = new Dataset();

   // Filled the dataset with the query, select Column1, Column2 from table
   if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
   {
      if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() != string.empty)
      {
          GetTableInfo(str,d);
      }
      else
      {
          return ds;
      }
   }

   return ds;
}
```

Even though my else condition got executed it is unable to get out from the function, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: you don't change `ds`, so how would you expect this recursion to terminate?

Comment: Didn't get you can you elobrate

Answer (score 0):

Return dataset which is returned in recursive method,

```
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() != string.empty)
 {
      return GetTableInfo(str, d);
 }
 else
 {
      return ds;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return statement:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    return GetTableInfo(str, d);
}

return ds;
```

The first return basically goes about processing the sub-elements, whereas the second one unwinds the stack.